# Finding exact numbers with Regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a requirement to find specific numbers in text however I'm getting false positives on substrings.

```
import re

test_string = """ <419501> :422675: 419508 adsfasdf11412129 """


regex_pattern = re.compile(r'(419501|422675|419508|412129)(\b|$)', re.I)

matches =  re.findall(regex_pattern, test_string)
print matches
```

this works well in some cases however it gives me a false positive for this string:

```
  adsfasdf11412129
```

Any instance of the number surrounded by white space, newlines, or special characters will be a valid hit. Any leading characters or numbers is a false positive. Any suggestions?

Comment: Use [`\b(419501|422675|419508|412129)\b`](https://regex101.com/r/geuKGA/1), with word boundaries on both sides.

Comment: Thanks! I should have figured that out